# Spotfire: Show default view of a table2 with limited IDs and load more data on demand when filters applied on table1

Tags: database, loading, spotfire, tibco, ondemand

I have two tables-

Table1 - containing one row for each ID.
Table2 - containing multiple rows for each ID. Its a more detailed table.

ID is the common column between them.

For each ID in Table 1 , there are approx. 1000 rows in Table2. So, when I import Table2 its slowing down the Spotfire performance, taking time to load.

Table1 is imported in Spotfire. I don't want to show the whole data from Table2 so, I want to have a default view of Table2 with limited IDs initially. And when the filters are applied on Table1, Table2 should change accordingly. Table2 should forget what was there in the default view and show those filtered IDs from Table1. I am not limiting the data from Table1 as entire table has to be shown.

Is this something that is possible in Spotfire? If yes, how can I achieve this?